# c# Can't Connecting with firebase and why SetTaskAsync returns nulls with your current code

Tags: c#, winforms, firebase-realtime-database

Just I'm Trying to insert a data From C# Windows Forms Application User control
 to My firebase.
I have Install Nuget Package "FirebaseDatabase.net".
I have checked AuthSecret and BasePath is correct, but why response i null. 
Im any thing missing ? Please Help Me don't Close this Question.

I'm Followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZMwwZHJXJc

```
using FireSharp.Config;
using FireSharp.Response;
using FireSharp.Interfaces;
IFirebaseConfig Config = new FirebaseConfig
    {
        AuthSecret = "xyz",
        BasePath = "https://xyz-56633a.firebaseio.com"
    };

IFirebaseClient Client;
Client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(Config);
        if (Client!= null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Connection");
        }
   private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new Data()
        {
            id = textBox1.Text,
            Name1 = textBox2.Text,
            Name2 = textBox3.Text,
            Name3 = textBox4.Text,
            Name4 = textBox5.Text,
        };
        SetResponse response = await Client.SetTaskAsync("NewList/" + textBox1.Text,data);
        Data result = response.ResultAs<Data>();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted" + result);
        }
     }
```

While the above Code runing

```
  MessageBox.Show("Connected");
```

is Working. But

```
  Data result= response.ResultAs<Data>();
```

Show Error As System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
And the Data is not inserted. Please Help me to Fix this or If any other way available forward to me

Comment: This means that _response_ is null and this means that the call to SetTaskAsync failed for some reason

Comment: Have you tried [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)...?

Comment: @Steve thank you for reply. I can't  found reason why response is null.  I  checked AuthSecret ,BasePath are correct. any thing i'm missing. Please Help me i'm new to this.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anything about a FireBaseClient and why it should not return a valid _response_ object

Comment: Then why closing this question and mention as duplicate?.I already know "response is null"  but why ? I think if i'm edit and  change my question  may i get answer. Please I kindly request you for help me to get answer to fix . Don"t Closing My Question @Steve

Comment: Reopened, but you should change something or it will be closed again. For example remove that error message from title and ask why SetTaskAsync returns nulls with your current code. As is it will be reclosed again

Comment: Thank you @Steve bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not get any more answer for "why is not working?" but i solve this issue.
This above code is correct is running in window form but not working in user control.
Hence i just copy the code to form and pass the the value from user control to  form.

Passing the values  from user control to form

```
   private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] product = {textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text };
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.UsercontroleData(product);
    }
```

Asyne in window form

```
  Internal async void UsercontroleData( string[] Product)
    {
        var np = new newProduct()
        {
            Id = "Execute PUSH",
            Category = Product[0],
            SubCategory = Product[1],
            Modal = Product[2],
            Brand = Product[3],
            Unite = Product[4],
        };
        PushResponse response = await client.PushTaskAsync("Product/List", np);
        newProduct ff = response.ResultAs<newProduct>();
        newProduct result = response.ResultAs<newProduct>();

    }
```